# Kafka KTable Append a value into In Memory Store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to append a value to a Store in Kafka Streaming, what I would like to do is if another message with the same ID comes in on a topic then I would add the message into a List as a Value

Something like:

1st stream iteration for ID 1

```
ID | Messages
1  | [1]
```

2nd stream iteration for ID 1, then update key 1's value

```
ID | Messages
1  | [1,2]
```

## Updated Code

The below is working but I now need to send my custom object into the topic and then append to the list but I am having trouble adding a custom Message object to the ArrayList

```
KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("processed-conv");

KTable<String, ArrayList<String>> conversations1 = textLines
                        .groupBy((key, message) -> message)
                          .aggregate( ArrayList<String>::new,
                                     (k, v, a) -> {
                                         a.add(v);
                                         return a;
                                     }, myStateStoreProvider );


//then  I am able to query the store later with the below
    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, ArrayList<String>> keyValueStore =
                        streams.store("StateStore2", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());

KeyValueIterator<String, ArrayList<String>> storeIterator = keyValueStore.all();
                while (storeIterator.hasNext()) {
                  KeyValue<String, ArrayList<String>> next = storeIterator.next();
                  System.out.println("messages for " + next.key + ": " + next.value);
                }
```

Comment: Assuming the list is serializable, you should be able to reduce/aggregate two events into a collection

Comment: Is there any such function where I wouldn't have to do the operation of reading the list updating new value and then writing the list to Ktable again?

Comment: REDIS has something like https://redis.io/commands/lpush where the values are inserted

Comment: No, there is no such built-in function in Kafka Streams, M_K.

Comment: I think you have to map all elements to lists of single elements, then group by key, then combine lists.

Comment: Thanks, please see my updated question. I'm still having problems sending custom objects through the stream. I will add another update later.

Comment: What if 1 is updated at backed end? Will it also be updated in array or just it add a new record in array?

Comment: @OwaisAjaz, appended to the array if Key 1 has been updated

Comment: Then how to achieve upsert?

Comment: @OwaisAjaz , that's not what I wanted, in this case append-only, you can delete the key by tombstoning the key